# Recursive summation between 2 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, recursion, sum

I have 2 tables: one of hierarchies:
X
X/Y
X/Z
X/Z/A
W/R
W/Q
W/R/D
W/R/E
....

and one of leaves:
X/Z/A/3
X/Z/A/4
X/Z/2
X/Z/6
X/Y/A/8
X/Y/A/9
W/R/E/1
W/R/E/2
....

I Also have a table that connects every leaf/hierarchy, to its father:
X/Z/A/3    X/Z/A
X/Z/A/4    X/Z/A
X/Z/A      X/Z
W/R/E/1    W/R/E
.....

now, for every HIERARCHY, I need to sum up the number of leaves, recursively. Meaning, for example, that X/Z/A will have 2, and X will have 6

Any ideas?!?!?

Comment: if you keep leaves in second table with full tree path why do you use third table?

Comment: I suggest you to give a look to http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html which clearly explains two models for tree data and the methods to get information from them